accessibilityIdentifier not working the same starting with iOS 15
The app on which I am working has it's ui tested using Appium. Because of this, I set accessibility identifiers on views.
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("some text")
            Text("more text")
        }
        // wrapper 1
        .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
        .accessibilityIdentifier("ID 1111111111111")
        // wrapper 2
        .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
        .accessibilityIdentifier("ID 2222222222222")
    }
}

(the code is oversimplified to ease the understanding of the problem)
Running the code above on iOS 14 would output this on Appium Inspector when inspecting the views:
 <XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" name="ID 2222222222222" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="false" x="157" y="408" width="76" height="41" index="0">
              <XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" name="ID 1111111111111" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="false" x="157" y="408" width="76" height="41" index="0">
                <XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="some text" name="some text" label="some text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="157" y="408" width="76" height="21" index="0"/>
                <XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="more text" name="more text" label="more text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="159" y="428" width="73" height="21" index="1"/>
              </XCUIElementTypeOther>
            </XCUIElementTypeOther>

So each group of accessibilityElement and accessibilityIdentifier would create a XCUIElementTypeOther with the same name property as the id set by accessibilityIdentifier.
With newer iOS versions these are not working anymore, here is the output on Appium Inspector when inspecting the views:
<XCUIElementTypeOther type="XCUIElementTypeOther" name="ID 2222222222222" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="false" x="157" y="408" width="76" height="41" index="0">
                <XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="some text" name="some text" label="some text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="157" y="408" width="76" height="21" index="0"/>
                <XCUIElementTypeStaticText type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" value="more text" name="more text" label="more text" enabled="true" visible="true" accessible="true" x="158" y="428" width="74" height="21" index="1"/>
              </XCUIElementTypeOther>

It looks like the first group of accessibilityElement and accessibilityIdentifier is no longer generating an XCUIElementTypeOther.
Is there a way to have the same output of iOS 14 on newer iOS versions?

shouldn't the modifiers go onto the actual views instead of the parent view? Having two modifiers on the same level like this, does not really make sense semantically. As mentioned in the comment below, the way to do this is using accessibilityRepresentations.

It looks like the previous output of iOS 14 is incorrect, and has since been fixed.
When you call accessibilityElement with the children argument, iOS replaces the accessibility element's children of the view you apply it to rather than creating new accessibility elements with each call.
The SwiftUI code is modifying the VStack container twice, setting the accessibility element up to group the Text subviews and setting the accessibilityIdentifier twice (so the second instance is overwriting the first).
You want to use a second view to create your second wrapper, then apply the outer accessibilityIdentifier to that.
If you want to create a different accessibility representation for your VStack, you may want to look at accessibilityChildren(children:)
or accessibilityRepresentation(representation:).

"You want to use a second view to create your second wrapper, then apply the outer" - so I tried to do that, but still not working, it gives the same result. I embedded the .accessibilityIdentifier("ID 1111111111111") and first VStack in another VStack and added the .accessibilityIdentifier("ID 2222222222222") to that VStack

@Claudiu did you try just adding the respective identifiers to the views itself? This should actually just work. No need to fiddle around with .accessibilityElement(children:...) as the accessibilityTree and the actual view hierarchy should look the same.
